# Evitar envío de formulario si no pasa validaciones con jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo una aplicacion MVC C# en la cual tengo una vista que tiene tres elementos inputs (Editorfor) y un jQuery Datatable. El usuario ingresa los datos de un cliente en los tres inputs (nombre, DUI e ISSS) y estos se guardan en la base de datos, y luego se carga el Datatable con información del cliente (nombre, DUI e ISSS) desde la base de datos.

Pero antes de guardar información en la base de datos, debo verificar que no hayan dos clientes con el mismo número de DUI e ISSS. Para ello reviso todas los registros que muestro en el datatable con la información especificada en los inputs correspondientes antes de realizar el submit de la información así:

```
$("#sentInfo").click(function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else
        e.returnValue = false;
    $("#idProveedor").val(proveedor);
    $("#idacme").val('ingresar');

    var table = $('#myTable');

    table.find('tbody tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        if ($(tr).find("td:eq(2)").html() === $("#idDUI").val()) {
            alert('ya existe el DUI');
            return (false);
        } else if ($(tr).find("td:eq(3)").html() === $("#idISSS").val()) {
            alert('ya existe el ISSS');
            return (false)
        } else {
            $("#FormEmp").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Esto me funciona bien (muestra las validaciones y no envia la información) en caso que:

- DUI-ISSS (son iguales y repetidos),
- DUI no repetido-ISSS repetido,
- DUI repetido - ISSS no repetido

Pero en el caso que tanto DUI como ISSS sean repetidos y entre ellos no son iguales (por ejemplo, DUI es 12345 e ISSS es 67890) entonces me muestra los mensajes de error pero me permite mandar la información.

¿Me pueden indicar qué estoy haciendo mal?

Por cierto, el orden de las validaciones siempre es mostrar el mensaje para DUI repetido y luego ISSS repetido, pero cuando no funciona siempre me muestra primero que el ISSS está repetido, luego que el DUI está repetido y después manda la información.

Comment: No acabo de entender tu pregunta. Pero se ve que te faltan validaciones, de acuerdo a lo que dices. Ahora mismo estás evaluando sólo 3 condiciones: 1. `if ($(tr).find("td:eq(2)").html() === $("#idDUI").val())` 2. `else if ($(tr).find("td:eq(3)").html() === $("#idISSS").val())` y 3. `else {...`la condición 3 se cumplirá cuando no se cumplan ni la 1 ni la 2. Por lo que dices tienes más de tres casos, y todos ellos deben estar reflejados en los `else if`. Con esos if tan largos  yo me siento y escribo **a mano** en un papel los diferentes casos, y luego escribo el código mirando el papel.

Comment: Releyéndote, puede haber **al menos 4 casos que deben ser evaluados** : **(1)**. DUI - ISSS son iguales y repetidos , **(2)**. DUI no repetido - ISSS repetido, **(3)**. DUI repetido - ISSS no repetido, **(4)**. DUI e ISSS no repetidos **AND** DUI e ISSS diferentes. Piensa tus condicionales como una especie de embudo donde al final el código tenga que entrar en el último `else`, porque es el único remedio que le queda. De todos modos parece una evaluación complicada y yo la haría con una función independiente del código a la cual le paso los valores  para que ella los evalúe.

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el fallo?